# Getting Groups with Guests via Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying to retrieve a list of Microsoft 365 Groups that have guest members via Graph.

I can get a full list of groups and then filter client-side, but the documentation says that the "members" property is queryable in the $filter clause, so I thought I'd be able to do something like this:

```
/beta/groups?$filter=members/any(x:x/userType eq 'Guest')
```

However, this is returning the following error:

> Property 'members' does not exist as a declared property or extension property

Has anyone managed to pull this off? Or can someone confirm that it's not possible to filter a list of groups based on its members? Is there any way to do this without filtering client side?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, as I've heard from the PM in charge of this part of Graph.

https://twitter.com/merill/status/1550312453111955456?s=20&t=i9RNt7-E2fXNCSoDxESO4w

> Unfortunately member is not available as a filter option for the group object so you will need to manually query each group.

Hopefully this gets added at some point, but for now I'm going to have to get the full list of groups and filter client-side.